# Can't switch context with Appium for Cordova hybrid app on Android 7

Tags: cordova, appium, android-7.0-nougat, hybrid

**[Appium 1.7.1] [Android 7.0] [Java] [Hybrid App] [Cordova]** 
I tried with following logic to switch context, it's working with another Android OS like 5.1.1 but it's not useful for android 7.0. I am not able to focus on native app after context from webview.

```
Set<String> availableContexts = driver.getContextHandles();

// switch to Web-view
   for(String context : availableContexts) {
     if(context.contains("WEBVIEW")){
        logger.info("Context Name is " + context);
        driver.context(context);
        break;
     }
   }

// switch to Native app
    for(String context : availableContexts) {
        if(context.contains("NATIVE")){
            logger.info("We are Back to " + context);
            driver.context(context);
            logger.info("Context Switched");
        }
    }
```

Comment: @dmle can you please help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After switching from web-view, I have kept the application in background for a while as per following, and then resumes execution:

```
driver.runAppInBackground(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
```

This is now resolved for issue faced while switching context view from web-view to native view.

**please suggest someone have the better approach.**

Answer (score 0):

There is not much to say without seeing appium server logs.

When you face such kind of issues (stopped working with new OS version update, new Appium server release, etc.) I recommend to print output of `driver.getContextHandles()` and see what you get.

Its not the first issue with Appium+Cordova and not available to switch context. If you will find out that you don't get `NAVIVE_APP` context, then you better report issue to [appium server project](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues)

Comment: after driver.getContextHandles() - I get **[NATIVE_APP, WEBVIEW_AppPackage]**. I think, I able to context 'NATIVE_APP' but not able to focus on it. Have you any solution to focus on page after context?

Comment: `driver.context(context)` is the right way. After you did it, you can print out `driver.getPageSource()` and check if you are still in webview or in native one.